# How to print a pair from array python?

Tags: python, terminal, console

I'm new on Python,

Code

```
bright_fruit = ['banana','orange','mango']
red_fruit = ['tomato','grape','apple']


for x in bright_fruit:
  for y in red_fruit:
    print(x, y)
```

and the result like this

```
>banana tomato
>banana grape
>banana apple
>orange tomato
>orange grape
>orange apple
>mango tomato
>mango grape
>mango apple
```

what i need is print pair from array like this

```
>banana tomato
>orange grape
>mango apple
```

I will use this code to more specific cases, but can anyone fix this?

thanks for help.

Comment: You want to use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) here

Comment: if the two arrays have the same length then you can use only one loop `for i in range(len(arr)) print(arr1[I], arr2[I])`

Comment: @odaiwa hi it works. Thanks A lot 
for i in range(0, 3):
  print(bright_fruit[i], red_fruit[i])

Answer (score 1):

Use the `zip` function:

```
bright_fruit = ['banana','orange','mango']
red_fruit = ['tomato','grape','apple']
for x, y in zip(bright_fruit, red_fruit):
    print(x,y)
```

Alternatively you could use the index value in order to print both:

```
for i in range(len(bright_fruit)):
    print(bright_fruit[i], red_fruit[i])
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering obvious duplicates. Flag / Vote to close instead

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
bright_fruit = ['banana','orange','mango']
red_fruit = ['tomato','grape','apple']

for fruit1, fruit2 in zip(bright_fruit, red_fruit):
    print(fruit1, fruit2)
```